# Поменять местами первую и последнюю букву в последнем слове

Tags: python

Дан текст, например: "я возьму твой хлеб".
Поменять местами первую и последнюю букву в последнем слове

```
s = input("Введите текст:")
d = s.split()
result = []
for i in d:
    result.append(i[-1] + i[1:-1] + i[0])
print(result)
```

Проблема в том, что он меняет весь текст:

```
['яя', 'уозьмв', 'йвот', 'блех']
```

Мне нужно одно конкретное слово чтобы поменял...

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: вам надо сначала разобрать текст на слова через `split()`, изменить последнее слово как требует задание, а затем собрать обратно текст через `join()`

Comment: Чтобы менять буквы в последнем слове, нужно для начала взять это последнее слово. А тут берется весь текст.

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = input().split()         # разбитие по пробелу
b = list(a[-1])             # отделяем последнее слово
b[0], b[-1] = b[-1], b[0]   # меняем местами буквы
print(*a[:-1], "".join(b))  # соединяем обратно
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = input("Введите текст:")
d = s.split()
last_word = d[-1]
if len(last_word) > 1:  # если последнее слово состоит из одной буквы, то делать нечего
    d[-1] = last_word[-1] + last_word[1:-1] + last_word[0]
print(' '.join(d))
```